# Bootstrap Columns Not Working - Error in Code

Tags: css

I cannot figure out what I am missing here.  (Head included for bootstrap reference.)

```
<head>:
<!-- Bootstrap Complete CSS -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Complete JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Complete JavaScript Bundle -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Problematic code:

```
<!-- TopGrid -->
<section id="TopGrid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="TopGrid-Box col-lg-4">
        <img class="Mask" src="Images\Mask Icon.png" alt="Lineart Face Mask">
        <h2>Masks</h2>
        <p>Our associates will be wearing masks, and you will be asked to do the same while shopping in our stores. </p>
      </div>

      <div class="TopGrid-Box col-lg-4">
        <img class="Hands" src="Images\Hand Cleaning Icon.png" alt="Lineart Hand Sanitizer">
        <h2> Hands</h2>
        <p>Hand sanitizer will be provided as you enter so we can maintain safer shoe displays. Our asociates will also be regularly using sanitizer as well as washing their hands
          throughout the day.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="TopGrid-Box col-lg-4">
        <img class="Surface" src="Images\Surface Cleaning Icon.png" alt="Lineart Cleaning Spray">
        <h2> Surfaces</h2>
        <p>Our associates will be disinfecting all high-touch surfaces throughout the day, as well as before and after customers.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I am not getting columns at all.  Removing the images doesn't affect it, adding a container doesn't affect it, adjusting screen size does not affect it.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I don't know what it is.

(There is no CSS currently written for this code, except for the inline bootstrap.)

Comment: don't you include the `bootstrap.css` file?

Comment: @GilangPratama I thought I had...

Comment: You can check here: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ `css` cannot be encripted in `script tags`

Comment: @SunLynx i think it is working if you copy the code and paste in codepen with bootstrap css link. maybe problem  is in TopGrid-Box which is not bootstrap class

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.  You helped sort it out.  It was a problem with the bootstrap references.

Comment: I think you should include the css with `<link>` sir